# How do I align the image left

Tags: html, css

I wrote this code:

```
<section  class="termine">
    <div   class="container">
        <img  class="img" src="https://www.buildinglogix.net/wp- 
         content/uploads/2017/01/BLX_Homepage-Banner.jpeg" 
         alt="image building">
    </div>
<h1 class="text1">Chi sono</h1>
  </section>
```

and this css:

```
.termine {
          float:left;
          display: block;
          align:left;
          width:100%;
          width:100%;
          position:absolute;
          margin: 0; padding: 0; border: 0; outline: 0;}



.container {
           display: block;
           align:left;
           width: 1290px;
           padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
           float: left;
```

}

```
.img {
         display: block;
         align:left;
         width:1290px;
         padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
         border: 0;
         margin: 0;
         outline: 0;
         float: left;  
         text-align: left;
```

}

please help me
Is it the bootstrap link the interfears with it?
How do I make it so that there's not white space?

Comment: Do you want the image to cover the whole screen?

Answer (score 0):

Your bootstrap CSS is being loaded after your updated container css. Move your custom css below the bootstrap css.

The bootstrap "container" class is overwriting yours.

It should look like this:

```
<head>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

  <style>
  .container {}
  </style>

  </head>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you included bootstrap in the page? If yes you don't need to rewrite the container class in it. Still if you want to widen the container you can simply write

```
.container { width: 1290px; }
```

The `align:left` in your written code is not working and is not necessary. No need to write `align:left` it while using `float` property.
Not only that, image by default align to left direction only. I don't understand you are you using `position:absolute` in "termine" div when you want simply to show the image inside the container.

Simply write HTML:

`<div class="container">
   <img src="https://www.buildinglogix.net/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/BLX_Homepage-Banner.jpeg" alt="img">
 </div>`

and then in CSS

`*, body { margin:0; padding: 0;}
.container { width: 1290px;}
.container img { width:100%; height:100%; vertical-align: top; }`

to achieve the image in full width height and aligned to left.
Hope the answer helped you.